# How did this character end up where they did in Star Trek (2009)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

In the first film of the J.J. Abrams [*Star Trek*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(film)) (2009) reboot, they find Scotty marooned on an ice planet.

I was watching with a friend who implied there was an in-universe explanation of how this person came to be there.

I don't want the explanation, but rather which film/episode/series of *Star Trek* do I need to watch to see how they got there?

Comment: It's in the film, I shouldn't answer in comments.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy - that's the whole answer I really wanted. I must have missed that bit.   Post an answer saying that it's actually in the same film and I'll upvote & accept it.

Comment: Aside - "marooned" and "posted" are not quite identical, but from the viewpoint of the personnel, the end result may be the same.

Comment: @Criggie Perhaps, but not knowing how they got there, marooned seemed the obvious choice. But you really should have not posted this as it’s a partial spoiler.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is given in the film itself (spoilers below, so stop reading now).

---

.
.
.
.

He was posted there as punishment for murdering Admiral Archer's dog.

> Kirk did not smile. “You’d be surprised at what I know. What did you
> do to get yourself posted to this vacation paradise?”
>
> Scott grew animated. “I got into a debate with my instructor on the
> issue of relativisitic physics as they relate to subspace travel. He
> seemed to think the range of transporting a, say, roast turkey, was
> limited to a few hundred kilometers. So I told him not only could I
> beam a bird from one planet to an adjacent planet in the same system,
> which is no big deal anyway, but that if I were so inclined I could
> actually do it with a viable life-form. Long-range transwarp beaming
> is supposed to be impossible.” He snorted. “Difficult maybe, but not
> impossible.”
>
> “Says you,” countered Kirk.
>
> “Says I, aye.” The engineer glared back at him. “My mistake was in
> attemptin’ a practical demonstration. Unfortunately, for a test
> subject I chose Admiral Archer’s prize beagle.” He shook his head
> sadly. “Shoulda scanned the little mutt’s ident implant first, I
> suppose.”
>
> Kirk’s expression changed to one of surprise. “I know of the
> admiral—and his dog. What happened to it?”
>
> Scott looked away. “I’ll tell ye when it reappears. I’m convinced it
> will, one of these days.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_(novel))</sup></sub>

The dog is, we learn

> [Not dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/96695/20774)